# Is the 10MB limit for a 3g App Store download for the zip or the binary?

Tags: iphone, distribution

I'm about to release my first app and I'd like for it to be able to be downloaded over 3g.

The binary is ~14MB, but when I compress it to a zip file it is just over 10MB. It's possible to cut out some content in order to squeeze it into 10MB, but I'm not sure if I have to cut out less than 1MB or ~4MB.

My question: When downloading an app from the App Store, does a compressed (zip) file get transferred to the device, or does the binary? Is the 10MB limit on the zip or the binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice,  I have seen my apps at 9.8 mb require wifi.  To be safe, I usually keep my zip file under 9mb

UPDATE: 2/27/10
Apple has recently updated this limit from 10MB to 20MB

Answer (score 3):

It is the IPA file that is transferred to the user.

Comment: Also note that Apple will unzip the file you send them, add a few small files and rezip it using the standard Finder zip routines. Be sure to leave a little padding

Answer (score 0):

I read Apple lifted this limit to 20 MB.